# Foot note/ End note numbering in Bengali in Libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice

Can anyone help me with how to enable Foot note/ End note numbering in Bengali language in Libreoffice?

Only options available (CTL>General Options>Nuerals) are:

- Arabic
- Eastern Arabic
- System
- Context

Answer (score 0):

1. Option → Language Settings → Language

   Set, Locale Setting: Bengali (Bangladesh)
2. Option → Language Settings → Complex Text Layout

   Set, Numerals: System

[image: Ubuntu - Libreoffice - Bengali Numerals]